# Unable to capture exit code of a script ran inside of a heredoc

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, here-document

I was playing around and got stuck while trying to capture the exit code of a script I'm running within a heredoc in a Docker container.

Say I want to run this command to start a Docker container loaded with `python:3.7`, and execute a heredoc inside of it.

```
docker run -v $PWD:/workspace -w /workspace --rm -i python:3.7 <<-EOF
    ./script.sh
    echo $?
EOF
```

Suppose `script.sh` looks like this:

```bash
echo 'Before'
exit 1
echo 'After'
```

When I run that, I don't get

```
Before
1
```

like I expected, but rather

```
Before
0
```

When I try to assign the exit code to a variable like

```
./script.sh
code=$?
echo $code
```

I get this:

```
Before
```

How can I reliably capture the exit code of `script.sh` which is run within a heredoc?

---

I imagine it has something to do with it running in a heredoc in the first place, as running that same sequence of commands within the container directly works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your here-document is not quoted, which means that the invoking shell will expand variables within it before passing it to `docker`.

Two solutions:

1. Quote the here-document by quoting any part of the initial here-document delimiter:

   ```
   docker ... <<-'MY_SCRIPT'
       ./script.sh
       echo "$?"
   MY_SCRIPT
   ```

   Any variant of `'MY_SCRIPT'`, `"MY_SCRIPT"`, or `\MY_SCRIPT` would work (even `'MY'_SCRIPT` etc.)  The actual delimiter should be a word and is usually written in upper-case. I've used a word that additionally describes the redirected document as a way of documenting the code.
2. Escape the `$` character within the redirected document to stop the shell from expanding that particular variable:

   ```
   docker ... <<-MY_SCRIPT
       ./script.sh
       echo "\$?"
   MY_SCRIPT
   ```

   This alternative solution is often used when the here-document contains a combination of variables that need to be expanded by the invoking shell and others that need to be passed as is.